# Disrespectful users... (Please read in its entirety)

Tags: discussion, editing

- I will be honest and direct.
- Before doing anything, please read the full text, I made it as simple as possible to have less problems to read it.
- Some people downvote without even trying to read the question.
- Also one people called 'two bugs' literally modified my whole question to make another one while it made it worse.
- I cite he changed my long question (which was hard to understand because it was long) I can accept that, but he literally trashed the question into *"Pokemon: Mystery Dungeon uses a quiz to determine your starter. The answers you give directly impact which starting Pokemon the game assigns you. What answers map to which Pokemon?"* First the exact game hasn't been precised, so nobody can understand which game was that supposed to be, it could be pokemon dungeon mystery red team/blue team, explorer of time/darkness ect.
- **I am not fluent in English grammar, because I'm French** and I would appreciate if everyone could at least try to read and understand the question, because if people are intolerant about my grammar/vocabulary, I can simply talk in **French**.
- Really, even a Reddit user said he got a ton of upvotes on Reddit but only got downvotes here, he **copy pasted his question**, so if the same question was accepted on Reddit, why not here?
- I joined this website over Reddit for two reasons: 1. It looks way better than Reddit which is really odd, 2. Unlike Reddit it doesn't have a bad reputation.
- **Now before you downvote, flag or remove the comment I would like if you think for 2 minutes and tell me how is it tolerable?**
- I know there is a ton of people, I know that the mods are choosen by the site itself, so bad/intolerant users can become moderators, I know that this website is not Reddit and I can't do whatever I want.
- But please, in all honesty, can you answer my 3 questions:

  1. Why don't you ban the bad moderators and keep the good ones.
  2. Why people disrespect newbies that much? Another good question got -9, while it was 100% fine and why can't anyone explains them why they shouldn't have downvoted/upvoted.
  3. Why instead of helping, the people goes into sh*tting on the users until they get ban. (Again a good question got -9)
- **Again before you downvote, edit, delete this post, think 2 minutes and just... just answer me please, why can't you explain to the intolerant users why they aren't correct and why they should try to understand the question before doing anything to it...**

Also here's the question I'm talking about: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/281920/revisions

Before finishing I hope I get your attention, it really has to change, because people could abandon the website.

Comment: I apologize for any trouble, I was trying to assist your question. I don't think trying to make a meta discussion about this is warranted as you made no attempt to contact me or resolve this in other methods. Again I'm sorry for the hassle, but I hope my intentions at least are clear.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the edit in question (revision 2) maintains the integrity of the actual question at hand. The only potentially important bit that was removed was the specific question "how do I get rilou", which would be answered by "how do I choose my starter"

Comment: A user edited your *admittedly hard to understand* question and made it clearer, so you are more likely to get an answer and upvotes. How is this in any way "intolerant"?

Comment: @KutuluMike It's more because I get since I created my account a ton of downvotes for no apparent reasons, again I said two persons made good questions, but only got downvotes.

Comment: Please try to understand that downvotes generally come from more experienced users enforcing our standards. If a question has a negative score, that's generally because it's a bad question in some way; either it's written poorly, or it's generally seen as not useful.

Comment: If they received downvotes, then it must be because someone did not think they were good questions. One way to avoid downvotes, for example, is to let the veteran users improve your question and stop undoing their changes, as those users are familiar with what is likely to attract downvotes and what isn't...

Comment: Okay, I want to go ahead and address this because it has been coming up a lot: *stop getting defensive about your spelling/grammar*. I don't speak for everyone, but spelling and grammar is the *last* thing I'm concerned about when I edit posts. I'll go through and correct it but I definitely don't consider you less of a person for making spelling/grammar mistakes. It's merely for the sake of readability. Maybe I had trouble reading your question. Maybe I think someone else might have trouble reading your question. So I edit your question so everyone else can read it. It's not an indictment.

Comment: The people you seem to have a problem with aren't moderators, they (@twobugs) are high-rep users who have got enough upvotes over time to increase their reputation to a point where it is assumed they know how the site works and what's on-topic and what's not, as well as how to formulate the questions in a way that's more likely to receive upvotes. Just felt like it had to be clarified...

Comment: @Chippies again I'm a newbie, so I can't really tell who are the moderators.

Comment: @Lumios For future reference, Mods have a diamond symbol next to their names. :)

Comment: @Lumios I just want to point out that yes, to newcomers, the way that this community handles voting does seem very harsh, but only because downvoting is seen as a 'bad' thing, rather than a 'constructive' thing. If you stick around (and hopefully you do), you will learn that a downvote is merely an indicator of lack of effort on your behalf. In fact the tool-tip for a downvote states *"does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful"*. You'll hopefully start to see them as less of an 'attack', and more of a helpful indicator to re-think your question/answer.

Answer (score 10):

> Some people downvote without even trying to read the question.

People are free to downvote as they want, but your question will get more upvotes as long as the content is good and the question is on topic.

> Also one people called 'two bugs' literally modified my whole question to make another one while it made it worse.

If a user damages your question, you are free to revert back to an older version, however if you do it when the edit is good, the question might be locked by moderators to prevent edit wars.

I know twobugs, even though we have disagreements sometimes, I've seen that all the actions he does on this website are did with good intent.

Please read this [short answer of mine](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11678/extremely-trivial-edits-from-2k-users/11679#11679), don't read the "trivial" words, that applies to every edit done by people over 2000 reputation (and if you broaden it a bit more, it applies to every edit)

> I cite he changed my long question (which was hard to understand because it was long) I can accept that, but he literally trashed the question into "Pokemon: Mystery Dungeon uses a quiz to determine your starter. The answers you give directly impact which starting Pokemon the game assigns you. What answers map to which Pokemon?" First the exact game hasn't been precised, so nobody can understand which game was that supposed to be, it could be pokemon dungeon mystery red team/blue team, explorer of time/darkness ect.

I think that the [edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/281920/revisions) was good and it clarified the question. Have to be honest here, reading a block of text and finding useful parts of it is not easy, so editing it to be more readable is a good edit.

> Also I do not use advanced english grammar, because I'm french and I would appreciate if everyone could atleast try to read and understand the question, because if people are intolerents about my grammar/vocabulary, I can simply talk in french.

We do not require perfect English (but we need English, so please don't post in French), but the question is needs to be understandable. People might and will edit to improve grammar issues.

> Really, even a reddit user said he got a ton of upvotes on reddit but only got downvotes here, he copy pasted his question, so if the same question was accepted on reddit, why not here?

We aren't reddit. Reddit has little to no moderation, while StackExchange has very strict rules about what content is allowed.

On StackExchange, as you gain reputation, you unlock more moderation powers which allows you to, for example edit without getting it checked by others (or revert edits done by others etc) or vote to close the question. We also have moderators that well, take care of users (banning sockpuppets etc) more than content (as I said, community takes care of most of the content).

The rules for the website is not set by the moderators but the users by discussing on meta. Every user has equal power (as long as you have enough reputation to participate in meta, upvote and downvote) on which direction the site will go.

> I joined this website over reddit for two reasons: 1. It looks way better than reddit which is really odd, 2. Unlike reddit it doesn't have a bad reputation.

See my answer above please, as I said, we are a much more strictly moderated website.

> Now before you downvote, flag or remove the comment I would like if you think for 2 minutes and tell me how is it tolerable?

What do you mean by tolerable? If you mean that those damage the new user experience, I agree, however they keep the quality high.

> I know there is a ton of people, I know that the mods are choosen by the site itself, so bad/intelerent users can become moderators, I know that this website is not reddit and I can't do whatever I want.

We have mod elections. StackExchange Inc. doesn't pick the moderators, users do.

> But please, in all honesty, can you answer my 3 questions: 1. Why don't you ban the bad moderators and keep the good ones. 2. Why people disrescpect newbies that much? Another good question got -9, while it was 100% fine and why can't anyone explains them why they shouldn't have downvoted/upvoted. 3. Why instead of helping, the people goes into sh*tting on the users until they get ban. (Again a good question got -9)

1) Our mods are pretty good IMHO. If they had ill intentions, they would be removed from their positions by StackExchange Inc.

2 and 3) As long as you follow the rules (when asking, answering and commenting), people respect and help the new users.

> Again before you downvote, edit, delete this post, think 2 minutes and just... just answer me please, why can't you explain to the intolerent users why they aren't correct and why they should try to understand the question before doing anything to it...

Ok, this answer will be a bit of my opinion. We are here to provide info to people in the clearest and correctest way possible, so we have rules that well, makes the questions answerable and help the most amount of people.

I think that the "intolerant" users just respect the rules and thinks that they are important to be followed by everyone. While this kinda damages the new users, it helps keeping the quality high.

Comment: I think we're confusing _actual_ moderator and high(ish) reputation users with power to do edits.

Comment: @DJPirtu will address that too in a minute, thanks.

Comment: I upvoted, you explained my trouble really well and made it a lot clear, thanks.

Comment: @Lumios And thank *you* for reading and taking the time to understand our actions. All too often people go on a blind rage and refuse to listen to us, always assuming that they're right and we're wrong. It's nice for someone to be understanding, for a change.

Comment: @agnussidney I'd upvote your comment twice if I could.

Answer (score 8):

You mention that this site has a better reputation than Reddit. Part of that reputation is that the community here works together to improve the site's content. We do that by asking and answering questions, by voting, and by editing questions and answers to improve them.

I understand that it looks like the user trashed your question to make a new one, and that is understandably frustrating. However when we see a question that can be improved, we want to improve it so that you (and anyone else who comes to this site with the same question) can get a better answer.

**Your original question:**

> in the quiz what should I answer to get a riolu as my starter... also if you have the time you can also list how to get each pokemon as starters

was rewritten to ask what the answers are to get each pokemon as a starter. To me, this looks like a great edit that clarifies your question and should get you the answers you are looking for as well as achieves your goal of avoiding a ton of similar questions for the other starter pokemon.

As a final point, you may want to look at [FAQ about why we edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/editing):

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. **If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.**

Comment: I want to let you know that I accept someone to change my question as long as it does make something out of this, but again, he made the question not understandable, that's what really irritated me. As long as someone makes something good out of this question, I'm fine.

Comment: "Part of that reputation is that the community here works together to improve the site's content." Then I hope everyone will try to be nicer and less judgemental. That would make a great improvement and make the site more "welcoming" (can't find the synonym of welcome) especially for those who discover the site.